# Storing data in Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a web site. This is a drupal site using PostgreSQL database.In this web site we can get direction data from one city to another by going to direction tab and giving start and end location.go to this URL and check that. http://www.zoomsrilanka.com/pathfinder .
     direction data is loaded to dashboard. I want export that direction data to a iPhone so that this data can be used another application in the iPhone. If I tell in another words I want to send that data and need to store in a iPhone so that it can be used for another task. I want to know that how to store data in iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control for the website you mentioned, You can create one webservice which will give you the required data in XML format by accepting parameters from iPhone.

i.e. you can call webservice from iPhone passing parameters and your webservice will provide response to that request in the form of XML and on receiving XML you can parse that and use according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to share data between different IPhone applications. Each application has it's own "storage".

Answer (score 0):

You can create API if you have access of server which you mentioned, API should give XML/JSON in response, so iPhone can take this response and parse accordingly, and store structure in sqlite local database.